# Fixing Footer in Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created a small fiddle but for some reason i have gray area in the bottom How do i get rid of it?

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LnWBE/).

This is my code

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="header" id="header" data-position="relative">

        </div>

        <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
            <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="info" data-expanded-icon="info" data-collapsed="false">

                 <h4 style="text-align:center;">Product Information</h4>
       <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="material">
<h5>
Serial#: W292059828
CD Key:  1545655465
Lisenced Users: 5
Active Sites: 10
</h5>
</fieldset>







          <h3 style="text-align:center;">Resource Software International</h3>
          <div id="addr"><p>40 King St. W., Suite 300, Oshawa, Ontario,L1H 14A <br />
          Phone: (+1)905-576-4575 Fax: (+1)905-576-4705 <br />
          http://www.telecost.com Email:rsi@telecost.com<p></div>
              </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - *which* Gray area is the problem?

Comment: you mean the grey area which is explicitly set via background-image gradient? I would suggest to remove the explicitly set background image css rule, then

Comment: can u edit my fiddle and show? i am referring to the gray area under the content div.

Comment: something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/LnWBE/1/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gray area you're noting is simply the unused real estate of the page since the footer isn't sticky. Try making your footer sticky: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

`.ui-page {background: #ccc;}`

That will set the background to match the colour that's used at the bottom of your content's gradient.